# asp.net mvc app in windows 2003 server extension less runs only home page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6, windows-server-2003, http-status-code-404

I've setup an asp.net mvc app on a windows server 2003 machine with IIS6. ASP.NET MVC3 and .NET4 framework has been installed.

Now, I setup a New Website, New AppPool for .NET4 and then put a virtual directory under there with my **asp.net mvc3/razor app.** So:

```
IIS
+NewSite <<I set home directory to MyApp
++MyApp/ <<virtual dir
```

Here is the annoying bit, when I navigate to the address `http://<MyServerIp>/` **the home page for my app loads up**. But, all other links/urls fail and give me a 404.

Like if I click *Log On*. The URL `<myServerIp>/Account/LogOn` gives a 404. Similarly all other urls other than the home page give me a 404.

I've gone through as many related questions on SO. I've gone through [Phil Haacks article.](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) I've setup a wildcard mapping for .net4.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that .NET 4.0 is enabled in the web service extensions folder in IIS manager console:

[image]

Also make sure that ASP.NET is properly registered with IIS:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Comment: Thanks +1 Yes, did check Web Service Extensions. Didn't register with IIS again. However could it be some mis-configuration because the Home page loads up? I even installed Orchard and its the same thing, home page shows up, but no url works?

Comment: @giddy, is the home page (`/`) served through an ASP.NET MVC controller action or is it an index.htm static file in the root?

Comment: Nope, its a controller action. Both for my app and for OrchardCms.

Comment: Oh oh! @Darin I don't think I unchecked the `Verify File Exists` when adding the wildcard mapping!! Could that be the problem!?

Comment: @giddy, I don't know, what happened when you tried uncheking it and restarting the server?

Comment: @Darin so I went to work and checked that box and that was all it took! Thanks so much! =D